# How do I add Spotify, or any oauth app to a user in my app?

Tags: python, oauth-2.0, oauth, spotify, spotipy

I'm currenty creating an app, where a user from my app/ database will connect to spotify and be able to access the users liked songs and other spotify api features. I'm having some trouble figuring out how exactly do I match a user in my app, with the user in the spotify api?

Do I need to store the auth tokens in my database and from there run api methods? Do I need to make a table in my database specifically for auth tokens?

In my current app, I've connected to the spotify api via their CLIENT_ID and SECRET token, but from my understanding that is my own data, and the website would only show data from whoever is logged in.